# Как вывести контент по следующей сетке

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести контен по следующей сетке 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот мои наброски.Как всётаки вывести инфу как ев картинке

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
                <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 3, 'showposts' => 6 ) ); ?>
                <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $i++; ?>
                    <?php if(in_array($i, array(1,4))) { ?>
                        <div class="column">
                            <div class="card">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb3x4'); ?><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <?php if(in_array($i, array(2,5))) { ?><div class="column"><?php } ?>
                            <div class="card">
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb3x2'); ?><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php if(in_array($i, array(3,6))) { ?></div><?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
```

Comment: Чем выводить хотите? Табличной версткой или блочной?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan блочной,хотя мне б просто вывести как на макете

Answer (score 1):

```
<?$i=0;?>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => 3, 'showposts' => 7 ) ); ?>
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php $i++; ?>
    <?php if(in_array($i, array(4))) { ?>

        <div class="column" style="width: 33.33333333%;">
            <div class="card card-<?=$i?>">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                 <a class="img-href-<?=$i?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(380,380,true)); ?><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
            <?php  endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php if(in_array($i, array(1,5))) { ?><div class="column" style="width: 33.33333333%;"><?php } ?>
        <?php if(in_array($i, array(3))){echo"<div class='clearfix'></div>";} ?>
            <div class="card card-<?=$i?><?if(in_array($i, array(1,2,6,7))):?> col-md-6 p0<?endif;?>">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                <a  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumb3x2'); ?><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <?php if(in_array($i, array(3,7))) { ?></div><?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```